# ASP.NET app double-hop issue when sending email to exchange

Tags: asp.net, delegation

I created an ASP.NET application for an internal purpose, where the domain user accesses a simple web form, fills in the form and submits. The application impersonates the user and sends an email as the logged on domain user to our ticketing system where a ticket is generated from the user who filled out the form. Now, everything works when I test by logging onto the same server that IIS (7.5) is located and submit the form, but when I try to do the same from my desktop (opening browser and pointing to web server), it does not work. After investigating the issue, I discovered that this is likely a double-hop issue (which I confirmed when the exchange admin checked logs after a few failed attempts and found that site was trying to send email as NTAuthority/Anonymous.)

I've combed the web and found a lot of info on this issue, but all I can seem find are articles detailing the issue in relation to earlier versions of IIS (IIS 5 or 6.) I’m using 7.5 so I’m not certain of how the process for resolving this would differ. Could someone who has had this issue on IIS 7.5 post the basic step by step instructions for resolving double-hop as it relates to IIS 7.5 and sending impersonated email to an Exchange server? Something to the effect of, step one – do this, step 2 – do this, etc…

Another question that I have is the following: Many articles that I have read specify setting up a service account for delegation, and then create SPNs...However with IIS 7.5, I have the option of using application pool identities. Would application pool identities work with delegating impersonation, or would a service account be required to fix the issue?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like your ASP.NET application is trying to determine the logged in user by their Windows network login credentials?

If so, all you should need to do is turn off "Enable Anonymous Access" in your IIS site and make sure that "Authenticated Access" has the "Integrated Windows Authentication" turned on. Then IIS should properly query the browser for their login info and the session should use the user's credentials. This assumes a few things about the client browser used and if something other than Internet Explorer is used, then you might also need to turn on one of the other authentication methods so that the other browsers will properly prompt the user for their network login credentials. Sorry I don't have a running IIS 7.5 server at the moment to give you the exact site properties and descriptions to look at. So if you cannot determine it from my description here, hopefully someone else might add on with that or I can try to follow up later if you need.

Comment: Hey dmarietta, thanks for the reply! That is correct, I am grabbing the credentials for the currently logged on user and passing them. Within IIS, in the authentication config (for the site) I do have asp.net impersonation enabled, windows auth enabled, and everything else disabled. I am pretty sure everything else is configured properly, so I just need to get the specifics for how to deal with the double-hop, which appears to be by design if delegation is not specifically enabled/allowed.

Comment: Once you know the user, why not just retrieve the SMTP email address for their account and then send the email via SMTP to avoid the whole authentication issue with Exchange? You should be able to send a message seemingly on behalf of an inbox on Exchange through the SMTP connector without having to authenticate the user. Refer to methods of using CDOSYS to send SMTP email.